# How to apply .draggable() to all elements with the same class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, webflow

.draggable is working fine when I target elements with ID but when I try by class, it's not working for any of the elements.

Below is my code, any idea what should be changed?

```
<script> 
 $( document ).ready(function() {    
  $( ".draggableImage" ).each(function( index ) {
   $( this ).draggable();
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggableImage").draggable();
});
```

```css
.draggableImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="draggableImage ui-widget-content">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=Image+1">
</div>
<div class="draggableImage ui-widget-content">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=Image+2">
</div>
<div class="draggableImage ui-widget-content">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=Image+3">
</div>
<div class="draggableImage ui-widget-content">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=Image+4">
</div>
```

You can use a selector, like `$(".draggableImage")`, to select all the elements with the same class. When you assign Draggable to this selector, each one gets the same initialization.